# How to call a function written in one controller from another controller in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 controllers called LoginController and RegisterController  and a function 'public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)' is defined in RegisterController.How can I call the same from LoginController?

I used `var result= new RegisterController().Encrypt(newpass, true);` code but results :
Error   4   Member 'AP.WebApp.Controllers.RegisterController.Encrypt(string, bool)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: Note: Usually it's not good idea to have utility methods in a controller and use them from another one. It will work, of course, but it's not logical because it isn't something that is only for that controller. Usually having a static method is an indication it needs to be elsewhere.

Comment: Better practice is to put all utility methods in different class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with inheritence.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller 
{ 
    //Common functionality between controllers go here
    protected static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, bool useHashing)
    {
        //Your content
    } 
}

public class LoginController : BaseController //not Controller anymore 
{
    //Encrypt is now available

    //...Your controller methods here
}

public class RegisterController : BaseController //not Controller anymore 
{
    //Encrypt is now available

    //...Your controller methods here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it's not good design to share a static method from one controller to another.

I suggest you create a new class, for example Common, that contains the definition of your shared function.  It could look like:

```
public class MyCommonUtilities
{
    public static string Encrypt(string ToEncrypt, bool useHashing)
    {
        // insert code here
    }
}
```

If you define this in a separate common project, then be sure to include this class in both of your controllers (note: not required if you define this class in the same namespace as the controllers)

```
using MyCommonUtilities;
```

and call it where you need it in each controller.  This centralizes the method into a common section of code and makes it available consistently to any controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is static on the register controller, so you shold just call:

```
RegisterController.Encrypt(newpass,true);
```

Or remove the static key word from the method.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a Encrypt class, which has Encrypt static class. Then you can call it from whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not good way to call one method from another controller. for that create common public class which can be access by anywhere from project.
One simple solution is create a method with `JsonResult` in `RegisterController` add your functionality and calculation in method. Call this method by http WebRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach, Create a base controller which inherited from Controller then this two controller will be inherited by newly created base controller which has common code ( Encrypt ) so that you can call method in both controller.